# how can I populate the other fields using textchange

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here's my code, any help will be appreciated.
Once I type the productid on txtbarcode.text and if it's existing in my database it should populate my txtitemdesc.textbox.

```
Protected Sub txtbarcode_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtbarcode.TextChanged
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source = pc11-pc\kim; Initial Catalog = convertpos; User Id = sa; Password = 123")
    con.Open()
    Dim sqlstr As String = ("Select * from Product where ProductID = @ProductID")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlstr, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", txtbarcode.Text)

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
        reader.Read()
        txtitemdesc.Text = reader("ProductName").ToString()
        MsgBox(reader("ProductName").ToString())
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the problem? where does your code fail / what happens? Is there any output or error message?

Comment: Actually sir when I put msgbox there the txtitemdesc will populate otherwise it won't populate.. =(

Comment: i didn't understand that either, but it looks like you have some render update problem...

Comment: I don't know what's is the problem there! but it was supposed to populate the txtitemdesc.text when I input a barcode. and I put message box there to see if it fetch some data and it did. but if I'd  remove the msgbox it won't fetch any info.

Comment: or maybe as you said I might have a problem in rendering.

Comment: possibly your reader("ProductName") fails. shouldn't it be reader["Productname"] ?

Comment: I check on it and I think that's correct. I apply my code on vb windows form and it's working. actually sir, this code will trigger through textchange does it affect the rendering?

Comment: that also might be the problem. Try .Update() and .PerformLayout() on the parent Component or textbox iteself.

Comment: I am new to this can you help me construct a code for that?